# WSO2 DAS. Vizualization event points on the map

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I would like to test GEO map gadget using WSO2 DAS.
I have a stream with geo coordinates (e.g.: latitude=51.509865, longitude=-0.118092). My goal is to show points on the map in real time (real time datasource) using Geo Map chart type. I set only Id, latitude and longitude properties (default for others). In the result I see the map without points any points.
I cannot find detailed information and examples in documentation. 
Is it possible or I have to use GPL - Siddhi Geo Extension?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Geo+Dashboard)

1. [Download](https://github.com/wso2-gpl/carbon-event-processing/releases/download/v2.0.4/p2-repo.zip) GPL feature as mentioned in the Prerequisites section.
2. As per the steps in the GPL feature installing [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Installing+WSO2+GPL+Features),

   - Start WSO2 DAS
   - Log into the DAS Management Console.
   - Click Configure in the side toolbar, and then click Features.
   - Click Repository Management, and then click Add Repository.
     [image]
   - Enter the details as shown below to add the created P2 repository.
     [image]
   - Click the Available Features tab.
   - In the Repository  parameter, select the  WSO2 GPL Feature Repository repository you previously added.
   - Remove the tick for "Group features by category" Click Find Features. Once all the features are listed, select the "GPL - Siddhi Geo Extension" feature and install.
3. Copy the two extension JAR files in the / samples/cep/utils/geo-dashboard-extensions/ directory to the  /repository/components/lib/ directory.
4. Navigate to the /repository/resources/geo-dashboard  directory and copy all the folders into the /repository/deployment/server directory.
5. [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geotools/files/GeoTools%2013%20Releases/13.1/geotools-13.1-bin.zip/download) GeoTools GIS toolkit

   - Copy the following client JAR files from downloaded  directory to /repository/components/lib/

     - gt-geojson-13.1.jar
     - gt-main-13.1.jar
     - gt-metadata-13.1.jar
     - jai_core-1.1.3.jar
     - jai_imageio-1.1.jar
6. [Download](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.8) JTS Topology Suite.

   - Copy jts-1.8.jar from /lib directory to both /repository/components/lib directory
7. Copy /samples/capp/org_wso2_carbon_geo_dashboard-1.0.0.car to /repository/deployment/server/carbonapps
8. Add <\Role>GeoDashboard</Role> to /repository/conf/carbon.xml under <\ServerRoles> parent tag
9. Add the Geo_DB datasource as mentioned in the 3rd step of [prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Geo+Dashboard#GeoDashboard-Prerequisites).
10. Restart the DAS server and you can access the dashboard via [this](https://ip-address:9443/portal/dashboards/geo-dashboard/) url
11. You can then simulate some events through the simulator and see.

    - Click Tools in the side toolbar, and then click Simulator.
    - Add the following and send the event.
      [image]
    - You will be able to see the sent information (Zoom out the map)
      [image]

Best Regards,
Ramindu.

Comment: Thanks! It works and I understand that I can use this option. But I can't use this map with other gadgets on a dashboard. Is it possible to use a live map using ui publisher?

Comment: I reproduce the same steps and I cannot see the send information using ant in wso2das-3.1.0\samples\cep\producers\tfl-feed\ any idea?